# How to change proxy setting manually in debian?

Tags: debian, proxy

I want to change my system proxy settings manually with command line.

What are the commands that allow to substitute this GUI operation on Debian 8.0?

1. Going to the menu and accessing the Network settings

[image]

2. Change the SOCK5 proxy IP and port

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To avoid going through Network Settings, you would need to define `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` variables system-wide.

This would usually be done by editing `/etc/profile`, adding something like this:

```
export http_proxy=http://proxy.example.com:3128/
export https_proxy=http://proxy.example.com:3128/
```